# Multiple Occurences of groups in java regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have query in finding the repeating groups in the below input string.

Objective:

**A line must have 4 or more occurences of [Key:value] pair.(with rectangular braces)**

Input:

```
<2014/06/14-11:03:06.695>+Timer-11+INFO@TimeLogger.logTime: [Process Name : Nav Calculations] [Total Time : 7 ms][Wait Time : 0 ms][Execution Time : 7 ms].
```

Snippet:

```
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[.*?\\]){4,}");
final Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

With the above snippet, the matcher couldnot find the match.

But if i change the pattern  to `"(\\[.*?\\]){3}")"` , it returns the below value.

```
[Process Name : Nav Calculations] [Total Time : 7 ms][Wait Time : 0 ms][Execution Time : 7 ms]
```

I went through the previous other posts regarding regex as well. But couldnt understand what am i missing here.

Why the regular expression `"(\\[.*?\\]){4,}"` does not work. What should I change in this regular expression to meet my objective

Kindly guide me from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one cannot find the match because there is a space between the groups.

You have a space here:

```
[Process Name : Nav Calculations] [Total Time : 7 ms][Wait Time : 0 ms][Execution Time : 7 ms]
                                 ^ space
```

As a result, you cannot match four sets of braces exactly one after the other. The space needs to be matched.

**Fixing the regex**

You could, on the other hand, match it if you had an optional space in your quantified group:

```
(?:\[.*?\]\s*){4} // This works!
```

**Why does `(?:\[.*?\]){3}` match four groups?**

1. The dot-star is allowed to jump over the space.
2. The first instance matches `[Process Name : Nav Calculations] [Total Time : 7 ms]`
3. The second matches `[Wait Time : 0 ms]`
4. The third matches `[Wait Time : 0 ms][Execution Time : 7 ms]`

**Reference**

The article below might remove any remaining confusion.

[The Many Degrees of Regex Greed](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html)

Comment: Instead of replacing the spaces, Is there a way to tell the regular expression to not consider the spaces while matching the pattern.

Comment: @user3739735 I beefed up the answer (see full explanation). When you say `"not consider the spaces"`, you mean like the new regex I gave you, right?

Comment: @when i say not consider the spaces, I meant , the regular expression should just look for four or more occurences of the rectangular braces with some text inside it. The regex should not fail, even when there are spaces between the braces. 

Can it be done via regex?

Comment: @user3739735 Excellent, then that's exactly what you have now. :)

Comment: Bull's eye..! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: String inputLine = "<2014/06/14-11:03:06.695>+Timer-11+INFO@TimeLogger.logTime: [Process Name : Nav Calculations] [Total Time : 7 ms]      [Wait Time : 0 ms][Execution Time : 7 ms].";


    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[(.*?:.*?)\\]\\s*){4}");

Its not matching in this case

Comment: @user3739735 I see it matching, are you sure you have escaped the backslashes that need to be escaped when you put the regex in Java? `Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("(?:\\[.*?\\]\\s*){4}");
 Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(your_original_string);
 if (regexMatcher.find()) {
  VideoID = regexMatcher.group();
 } `

Comment: Yea I gave the pattern like "(\\[.*?\\]\\s*){4}"

Comment: @user3739735 Pls look at my comment above... You're missing backslashes. When you use a regex in Java you need a backslash before a regex backslash. Your `"(\[.*?\]\\s*){4}"` needs to be `"(\\[.*?\\]\\s*){4}"`